# Enumeration Constants as Array Subscripts in VB6

Tags: vb6

I'm defining an enumeration which may end up being used as an array subscript like this...

```
Public Enum MY_ENUM
    THIS_ENUM_VALUE = 1
    THAT_ENUM_VALUE
    THE_OTHER_ENUM_VALUE
    MAXIMUM_ENUM_VALUE = THE_OTHER_ENUM_VALUE
End Enum
```

The theory is that anyone adding another enum will correct the maximum enum value and any array defined as

```
Dim my_array(MAXIMUM_ENUM_VALUE) As Integer
```

will get enlarged as required.

My question is: ought I to be doing this, and if not, what would you suggest?

Comment: Looks like you are storing different data in different columns of a 2D array? Possibly you should be using structures (`Type`) or objects (`Class`) instead?

Comment: @MarkJ, thanks for the tip but I'm just using these enums as array indexes; I'd say `myarray(FRONT)` and `myarray(BACK)`, for instance, are preferable to `myarray(1)` and `myarray(2)`.

Comment: In that case why not `myarray(LBound(myarray))` and `myarray(UBound(myarray))` ? I still don't understand the need for the enums - of course it could be me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Practice is that we use declaration like

```
Public Enum MY_ENUM
    THIS_ENUM_VALUE = 1
    THAT_ENUM_VALUE
    THE_OTHER_ENUM_VALUE
    MAXIMUM_ENUM_VALUE
End Enum
```

and you even don't need edit last declaration :) Sure you have your arrays one element longer than needed, but IMHO that is not big problem.

Answer (score 4):

Note that it's also fairly typical in VB6 to use "hidden enum values" like this:

```
Public Enum MY_ENUM
    THIS_ENUM_VALUE = 1
    THAT_ENUM_VALUE
    THE_OTHER_ENUM_VALUE
    [_first] = THIS_ENUM_VALUE 
    [_last] = THE_OTHER_ENUM_VALUE
End Enum
```

You could combine this with the other suggestions:

```
Public Enum MY_ENUM
    [_first]
    THIS_ENUM_VALUE
    THAT_ENUM_VALUE
    THE_OTHER_ENUM_VALUE
    [_last]
End Enum

Dim MyArray(MY_ENUM.[_first] To MY_ENUM.[_last]) As MY_ENUM
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that's the way to go. If you do as you've outlined, the enum can be expanded without breaking the code.

The only thing I see needs to be done is to inform others who use your code to declare arrays based on the enum to use `MAXIMUM_ENUM_VALUE` instead of their enum value they added (in this case, `THE_OTHER_ENUM_VALUE`).